# check if the email is real ( .gmx, .gmail, .live, ... )

Tags: php, email, email-verification

I've downloadet this verify e-mail class:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/6650/download/zip.html

and it mostly works well. if I'm trying to test a : @gmx/@live-mail, it allways say: this email doesn't exist. But I know that they're existing ( cause these are my emails ). I don't really now why? the information I'm getting if I'm searching for @gmx/@live are:

@live:

```
220 BLU004-MC1F11.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Thu, 21 Apr 2016 02:21:42 -0700 
Connection success mx1.hotmail.com
HELO bla.is
250 BLU004-MC1F11.hotmail.com (3.21.0.236) Hello [217.13.193.253]
MAIL FROM: <blabla@bla.is>
250 blabla@bla.is....Sender OK
RCPT TO: <unicorncookie@live.de>
550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
RSET
QUIT
email <unicorncookie@live.de> does not exist!
```

@gmx:

```
220 gmx.net (mxgmx008) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
Connection success mx00.emig.gmx.net
HELO bla.is
250 gmx.net Hello bla.is [217.13.193.253]
MAIL FROM: <blabla@bla.is>
250 Requested mail action okay, completed
RCPT TO: <unicorncookie@gmx.net>
550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
RSET
QUIT
email <unicorncookie@gmx.net> does not exist!
```

Does anyone have an idea why this class cant reach there mailbox? is it maybe because I'm using the port 25? I've never did something like that, so I'm really confused

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you checked your server i.p. isn't blacklisted for some providers? It's unlikely but worth checking if only to rule it out You can check it out here --> http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx [link](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

Comment: I tried it but everything seems okay. I also found out that on many different other websites for verifying emails you also can't find emails from @live/@gmx :) so it's not a mistake on my site :)

Comment: Well, at least that's a relief! I'm guessing that it's probably a protection method being employed by the external server to prevent email address harvesting in this case.

The reason for the external mail server to employ this is that you could write a script to simply loop through possible email address, see if they exist, then send emails out to them.

So, some servers will instead block requests from requests of certain formats.

Your best alternative bet would be to send an email as opposed to a quick username scan and include a unique something to determine if the email has been opened